# Jquery, Local Storage, and Changing Links depending on Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, hyperlink

First of all let me state that my coding experience is very little, which is why I'm coming here in the first place. I have a javascript/html 5 issue and/or question. I would like to have local storage save my checkboxes. That I have figured out using http://jsfiddle.net/TzPW9/330/.

```
HTML:
<div class="check">
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Name" id="name" checked /> <label for="name">Name</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Reference " id="reference" checked /> 
<label for="reference">Reference</label></p>
</div>

<div id="nametxt"> Show Name TEXT </div>
<div id="referencetxt"> Show Ref TEXT </div>

JAVA:
function getStorage(key_prefix) {
// this function will return us an object with a "set" and "get" method
// using either localStorage if available, or defaulting to document.cookie
if (window.localStorage) {
    // use localStorage:
    return {
        set: function(id, data) {
            localStorage.setItem(key_prefix+id, data);
        },
        get: function(id) {
            return localStorage.getItem(key_prefix+id);
        }
    };
} else {
    // use document.cookie:
    return {
        set: function(id, data) {
            document.cookie = key_prefix+id+'='+encodeURIComponent(data);
        },
        get: function(id, data) {
            var cookies = document.cookie, parsed = {};
            cookies.replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]*);?\s*/g, function(whole, key, value) {
                parsed[key] = unescape(value);
            });
            return parsed[key_prefix+id];
        }
    };
}
}

jQuery(function($) {
// a key must is used for the cookie/storage
var storedData = getStorage('com_mysite_checkboxes_'); 

$('div.check input:checkbox').bind('change',function(){
    $('#'+this.id+'txt').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
    // save the data on change
    storedData.set(this.id, $(this).is(':checked')?'checked':'not');
}).each(function() {
    // on load, set the value to what we read from storage:
    var val = storedData.get(this.id);
    if (val == 'checked') $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
    if (val == 'not') $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    if (val) $(this).trigger('change');
});

});
```

I modified it to my needs some. However I know less about java then I do about html, so that's where my issue comes in. I don't need the text in the previous example

```
<div id="nametxt"> Show Name TEXT </div>
<div id="referencetxt"> Show Ref TEXT </div>
```

to show up if I have a box checked. So I deleted it from the html, but I know the java is now verbose. I don't know what entries to take out of javascript so that it only saves the state of the checkboxes.

My next problem is that I want to turn all the text of the checkboxes to a link. I can do that myself. The problem about it is that depending on how many of the ones marked glyphs are checked, I want it to go to a different page. It doesn't matter which ones, just how many. So if 1 of them is checked it goes to one page, 2 of them it goes to another page, and so on and so on. In my example it would go to a total of 6 different pages depending on how many of the glyphs were checked. The feathers don't matter. I haven't made any of them links yet because I'm not sure how to code them if I want them to go to different pages depending on which ones are checked.

The third and final problem is that I have these in different pages, similar to this.

Page 1:

```
 <p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 1" id="Feather 1"/> 
<label for="Feather 1">Feather 1</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 2" id="Feather 2"/> 
<label for="Feather 2">Feather 2</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 3" id="Feather 3"/> 
<label for="Feather 3">Feather 3</label></p> 
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Glyph 1 - Santa Maria Novella" id="Glyph 1 - 
Santa Maria Novella"/> <label for="Glyph 1 - Santa Maria Novella">
Glyph 1 - Santa Maria Novella</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Glyph 2 - The Water Tower" id="Glyph 2 - The Water Tower"/> 
<label for="Glyph 2 - The Water Tower">Glyph 2 - The Water Tower</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="Glyph 3 - Windmill" id="Glyph 3 - Windmill"/> 
<label for="Glyph 3 - Windmill">Glyph 3 - Windmill</label></p>
```

Page 2:

```
 <p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 1" id="Feather 1"/> 
<label for="Feather 1">Feather 1</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 2" id="Feather 2"/> 
<label for="Feather 2">Feather 2</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 3" id="Feather 3"/> 
<label for="Feather 3">Feather 3</label></p> 
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Glyph 1 - The Forest" id="Glyph 1 - The Forest"/> 
<label for="Glyph 1 - The Forest">Glyph 1 - The Forest</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="Glyph 2 - Villa" id="Glyph 2 - Villa"/> 
<label for="Glyph 2 - Villa">Glyph 2 - Villa</label></p>
```

Page 3:

```
 <p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 1" id="Feather 1"/> 
<label for="Feather 1">Feather 1</label></p>  
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 2" id="Feather 2"/> 
<label for="Feather 2">Feather 2</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" value="Feather 3" id="Feather 3"/> 
<label for="Feather 3">Feather 3</label></p> 
<p><input type="checkbox" value="Glyph 1 - Alamo" id="Glyph 1 - Alamo"/> <label for="Glyph 1 - Alamo">Glyph 1 - Alamo</label></p>
```

The way I have things now, any page that has one of those checkboxes, the checkbox stays consistent. Which is what I want. The code for counting the glyphs though, I want that to count the cookie or local storage data, since I have it all across multiple pages.

So to summarize, I need my final javascript to be less verbose and I need to go to a different page depending on how many of the glyph checkboxes are checked, even if the checkboxes are on different pages. It doesn't matter which ones, just how many. I'm ok with changing the names/ids of them to just be Glyph 1, Glyph 2, Glyph 3, Glyph 4, Glyph 5, and Glyph 6, or whatever else I have to, but I'd rather not.

Here is the code I have now to edit. http://jsfiddle.net/TzPW9/335/

I hope I have given enough information and gave it clearly.

Comment: How about using the polyfill from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) for consistency ?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, lol. I don't code much. I know some html, but that's about it. The rest I have is copy and paste, getting lucky, and dreamweaver. What you just said is WAY over my head.